# hadoop distcp raises Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, distcp

When I'm running distcp to move data from s3 to my local hdfs i get this exception during the map reduce job launched to copy the data:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster
```

I checked every online article possible.
My `yarn-site.xml` file contains

`<property>
        <name>yarn.application.classpath</name>
        <value>
                $HADOOP_CONF_DIR,
                $HADOOP_COMMON_HOME/*,
                $HADOOP_COMMON_HOME/lib/*,
                $HADOOP_HDFS_HOME/*,
                $HADOOP_HDFS_HOME/lib/*,
                $HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME/*,
                $HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME/lib/*,
                $HADOOP_YARN_HOME/*,
                $HADOOP_YARN_HOME/lib/*,
                $HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce/,
                $HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/
        </value>
    </property>`

for every node of the cluster, I checked and those variable are set and point to the right folder, actually `$HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce/`is the one that points to `hadoop-mapreduce-client-app-2.7.1.jar`that is the jar that contains `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster`
Any suggestions??

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and spent few days to resolve. 
There was an issue with missing

```
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.application.classpath</name>
    <value>
       $HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME/*,
       $HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME/lib/*,
       $MR2_CLASSPATH,
       $CDH_MR2_HOME
    </value>
</property>
```

in mapred-site.xml

Here is the whole path I had to go through (in case someone will have to investigate similar issues):
 After the job run I could see an error in the client  log like this:

Exception from container-launch:

```
org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ExitCodeException: 
    org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ExitCodeException: 
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:505)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:418)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:650)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:195)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:283)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:79)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

    Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1
```

Also I have noticed **Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster** in job execution log.

To figure out you can go to the log directory on **NodeManager** host defined by **hadoop.log.dir** option in yarn configuration  (in my case it is  **/var/log/cloudera_logs/hadoop-yarn/**). There you will see the file **hadoop-cmf-yarn-NODEMANAGER***. It can help you to follow all workflow including running scripts, and clean-up process within the **./container** directory.
Here it is good to pay attention to the script **default_container_executor.sh**.
This scrip usually does an export of all system variables before lunching the job. In my case everything related to **$HADOOP_MAPRED_*** was missing.

Then I started looking to my server configuration options to find **mapreduce.application.classpath** option, which already pointed to the proper variables. For some reason they were not applicable when the job was running.

After this I tried to add the same variables on the client side to **mapred-site.xml** and it worked.

Pay attention that your **$HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME** should point to the valid location of **hadoop-mapreduce-client-app-.jar**, where **org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster** was packaged. Use advanced search in MAVEN CENTRAL if you're not sure which jar your missing class belongs to.

My guess is that it can be somehow related to **yarn.nodemanager.env-whitelist** option. According to the Cloudera "Environment variables that containers may override rather than use NodeManager's default.", but I'm not sure about it.

Answer (score 2):

Effectively, this is an issue with yarn classpath. You can see the defaults in the doc (https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-common/yarn-default.xml search for yarn.application.classpath).

So to solve it, make sure the environments variables are correctly set, especially the HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME that should points to the directory where the hadoop-mapreduce-client-app-.jar is located.

Normally, the following should works :

**yarn-site.xml**

```
<property>
 <name>yarn.application.classpath</name>
 <value>$HADOOP_CONF_DIR,$HADOOP_COMMON_HOME/*,$HADOOP_COMMON_HOME/lib/*,$HADOOP_HDFS_HOME/*,$HADOOP_HDFS_HOME/lib/*,$HADOOP_YARN_HOME/*,$HADOOP_YARN_HOME/lib/*,$HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME/*,$HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME/lib/*</value>
</property>
```

**mapred-site.xml**

```
<property>
<name>mapreduce.application.classpath</name>
<value>$HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME/*,$HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME/lib/*</value>
</property>
```

With, for example HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME pointing to /usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce

I take a long time to try to make everything OK on some docker container and finally I skip the environment variables and hardcoded the libraries directories in the config files and it works.

In my environment (but you need to replace with the correct directory for yours) :

**yarn-site.xml**

```
<property>
<name>yarn.application.classpath</name>
<value>/etc/hadoop/conf,/usr/lib/hadoop/*,/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/*,/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/*,/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/*,/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/*,/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/*,/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/*,/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/lib/*</value>
</property>
```

**mapred-site.xml**

```
<property>
<name>mapreduce.application.classpath</name>
<value>/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/*,/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/lib/*</value>
</property>
```

Maybe your issue is like mines, just some environment variables not applied when the container are launched.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this problem.
In my hadoop release version,there is no directory **$HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce/**,and **$HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/**,
but have directory **$HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce1/** and **$HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce2/**.

Fix the directory path,just OK.

Be careful,don't copy the default value in yarn-default.xml！！！